# No. of 3 letters word that can be made from the word INEQUALITIES without repetition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

No. of 3 letters words can be made from the word **INEQUALITIES** *without repetition.*

So i did this, i separated unrepeted letters from repeted ones, which looked like..

repeatation= {I,I,I,E,E} & without repetition= {Q,L,N,U,A,T,S}

SO, no of words made from 7 letters without repetition = ⁷P4 = 210

& Number of 3 letter words without repetition that can be made from repetition =  5! / 3! 2! = 10

Total= 210+10= 220,
So answer seems right  but i am not sure of approach! Any guidance will help very much.

EDIT1: 
Answer is right i.e 220.
EDIT2: Without repetation of Letters.

 220 claimed by my misprinted book is wrong answer.  "504" is the right answer.

 *★*
if followup question would be to find with repetitions of letters than 553 is the answer.

Comment: Your count doesn't include things from both your sets, like EEQ. By the way you say your answer "seems right" but are you saying it matches some answer you have for the exercise, in a text or something?

Comment: Can you provide a solution for the problem ?

Comment: kunal-- could you say whether you have gotten 220 by reading it as the answer? I may look at it later but have no time now.

Comment: --coffemath no, i just thought how to approach answer, & came with this

Comment: Can you reproduce the *exact* question ?

Comment: --true blue anil it is written there. Find the no of 3 lettered words that can be made from the word INEQUALITIES, Without any repeatation.

Comment: Can any one of you craft an answer, please!

Comment: If that is the exact question, your approach is not correct at all. You have $9$ distinct letters and you need to choose $3$ letters from it and permute.

Comment: Yes, i am aware but dont know how to produce an correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the **exact** wording is **"without repetitions"**
I would interpret it as no letter being used more than once in the word, which makes it quite easy.

There are $9$ **distinct** letters, $I\,N\,E\,Q\,U\,A\,L\,T\,S$

thus number of  number of $3$ letter words = $P^9_3 = 9\cdot8\cdot7$

Comment: Reasonable interpretation, but begs the question: if this is the intended interpretation, why choose a string of letters that includes "III" and "EE".  Further, the OP, upon seeing the very first comment posted, did not immediately respond by saying that "EEQ" was disallowed.  On the other hand, I agree that the problem's wording is ambiguous.

Comment: @user2661923: Yes, the wording is ambiguous, that's why I asked OP whether he had reproduced the **exact** wording, and he replied affirmatively.

Comment: The exact wording is: The no of 3 letters word that can be made from the word INEQUALITIES if repetitions of letters is NOT allowed

Comment: --user2661923 i corrected that error, no words like NQN,EEQ are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum added to respond to OP's comment.

---

I agree with coffeemath's comments.  Your $\displaystyle \frac{7!}{4!}$ computation represents 3 letter words that exclude any "I" or "E" letters.  I'm unsure what your $\displaystyle\binom{5}{2}$ computation is then supposed to represent.

Personally, I would break the situation into mutually exclusive cases, letting $T_k$ denote the computation for Case $k$.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~3~ \text{I's are used.}}$
This can only occur with the specific word III. 
$T_1 = 1.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2: A double letter was used.}}$
There are $2$ ways of choosing whether to use $2$ I's or $2$ E's. 
Assume that $2$ I's are used.
Then, there are 8 ways of selecting one letter from 
{ENQUALTS}. 
Once the *off* letter is chosen, there are 3 positions that the off letter may be placed in. 
Therefore, 
$T_2 = 2 \times 8 \times 3 = 48.$

$\underline{\text{Case 3: Only 1 of each type of letter was used.} }$
Then, there are $\displaystyle\binom{9}{3} = 84$ ways of selecting $3$ distinct letters from 
{EINQUALTS}.
Once these three letters are selected, they can be permuted in $3! = 6$ ways. 
Therefore,
$T_3 = 84 \times 6 = 504.$

---

Final computation:

$$T_1 + T_2 + T_3 = 1 + 48 + 504 = 553.$$

---

**Addendum**
Based on the OP's comment, Cases 1 and 2 above are disallowed.  This implies that, since only Case 3 is allowed, the final computation should be $T_3 = 504$.

Again, I am at a loss as to how to *reverse engineer* an interpretation that justifies the computation of $(220)$ as the final answer.

Comment: The motive behind my calculation is to reach the answer which is 220! I understood each part of your calculation but am not sure as your answer differs. --True blue anil 's answer also differs from your's as well as books, but i found your ones more understandable.

Comment: @kunalCh. I am at a loss to *reverse-engineer* an interpretation of the problem, for which the right answer is $(220)$.  Where my interpretation differs from true blue anil's interpretation is that I think that the intent of the problem composer is that the letters are to be treated like "*scrabble tiles*",  where if you have two "E" tiles, you can use both of the tiles.  Why else present a word with $3$ I's and $2$ E's?  Just to create a poorly worded *trick question*?

Comment: This problem already exists, in my book. Pardon me on behalf of my book. @user2661923

Comment: I realized just now, your computation is fine with repetition of letters. We are intrested in without repetition of letters hence words like III or 2 letters of same kind cases won't arise.

Comment: I agree that the "scrabble tiles" interpretation is better. "Without repetition" could just mean without reselecting a particular already-selected letter.